# jQuery / JavaScript HTML5 responsive Video Gallery plugin playlist youtube?

Tags: jquery, youtube, responsive-design, html5-video, lightbox

Does anyone know of a simple jQuery video player that can open in a lightbox like pretty photo and player a video with a small gallery and a playlist of other videos attached.

I'd like to link to one video by clicking on and image it would open in a lightbox and display the 1st video with a small gallery of others beneath maybe that would also be contained within the lightbox.

I've been looking at this - http://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-video-gallery-html5-youtube-vimeo/2918602?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=Tean

but a developer below gave me something called twitter bootstrap, which appears appears quite flexible
However is there a way to get the responsiveness to work with the right scrollbar?
http://brightmist.co.uk/test/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 1):

OP,

Check this Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YKoTWH?p=preview

#### Details

In summary, we ask the youtube API for a JSONP response about a specific playlist, loop over the results and build the list.

Behind the scenes, we append the collection to a [Twitter Bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

User clicks modal reveal button -> first video is triggered to load -> user clicks on other video thumbnails -> that video loads in its place.

This can absolutely be optimized/cleaned-up, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Wow thanks couzzi sounds fascinating. Is there a tutorial for this. I'm a designer/front end developer so have limited knowledge of javascript. I want something like this http://www.interactivepixel.net/ccVideoPlayer/index_v_right_100.html#/mix2/youtube_single1, but also with a lightbox function so it doesn't fill the screen completely.

Comment: I didn't even know what a modal was. I guess this may be better for seo than using an I frame in a lightbox!

Comment: Hi Couzzi, I've updated my question. Tried editing bootstrap modal with firebug with some success. Do you know if its easy to make it more responsive so that the thumbnails stay on the left or even stretch out underneath when on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [videolightbox](http://videolightbox.com/)..

It has a wide variety of video player styles and probably mac style is what you looking for.

Its easy to implement and also works on mobile devices.

OR

also there is an old quality video player like [sublimevideo](http://sublimevideo.net)

actually i recommend sublimevideo cause it has far more quality than all other video players around and has analytic page that shows how many people watched your video.